# Bash loop thru files not working as expected

Tags: bash

Why is my code below not working as expected?

```
shopt -s extglob || {

    echo "Unable to enable exglob."
    exit 1

}


TARGETEXT='.jpg'

TARGETPREFIX='./' ## Make sure it ends with /.


while IFS= read -r FILE; do

    BASE=${FILE##*/}

    NOEXT=${BASE%.*}

    TARGETFILEPATH=${TARGETPREFIX}${NOEXT}${TARGETEXT}

    duration=$(ffprobe -i "$FILE" -show_format -v quiet | sed -n 's/duration=//p'| sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//')
    space=$(awk '{print $1/$2}' <<<"$duration 5")

       echo ffmpeg -ss "$space" -i "$FILE" -vf "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,"$space")',sca
le='if(gt(a,4/3),206,-1):if(gt(a,4/3),-1,154)',pad=w=206:h=155:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=black,tile=4x1" -aspect
 4:3 -frames:v 1 -vsync vfr "$TARGETFILEPATH" -y

done < <(exec find -type f -name '*.mp4')
```

I have 2 mp4 files in the directory. If I run this code it work fine with 'echo' in front of the ffmpeg command. It'll output 2 lines of ffmpeg, one line for each file. Filenames are correct and all looks perfect.

When I run the same, removing 'echo', the first ffmpeg command will run successfully and my script will give an error for the 2nd file name. I can see in the ffmpeg output that there is one character missing at the beginning of the filename(should be uscenes.mp4).

```
scenes.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are the double-quotes around `"$space"` important? Looks suspicious. What if you remove them?

Comment: Why suspicious? `"$space"` will give me the value of the variable as same as `"$file"` does.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I meant in this part: `"select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,"$space")',sca
le='..."`. You have a parameter there correctly enclosed within double-quotes, but then within the outer double-quotes you have `"..."$space"..."` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: If I run the script with `echo` it works fine, so that cat be the issue. f`fmpeg -ss 3 -i ./big_buck_bunny_480p_5mb.mp4 -vf select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,3)',scale='if
(gt(a,4/3),206,-1):if(gt(a,4/3),-1,154)',pad=w=206:h=155:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=black,tile=4x1 -aspect 4:3 -f
rames:v 1 -vsync vfr ./big_buck_bunny_480p_5mb.jpg -y
y` You see the value '3'?

Comment: The fact that it works with `echo` only rules out basic syntax issues. It does not rule out semantic issues. For example, both `echo one two` and `echo "one two"` will print the same thing, but `touch one two` and `touch "one two"` will do very different things. So I'm asking, why do you have those double-quotes there? Do you understand what that actually does? In the string `"abc"$space"efg"` the `$space` is between two double-quote strings, but itself is not quoted.

Comment: Ok I see. If the value of `$space` is a simple number like 3 as in your example, then it's fine that it's unquoted. So indeed that cannot be a cause of your problem, but I still recommend to improve that, for the reason in my previous comment.

Comment: Got you! I removed the variable $space for testing and replaced it with a number. The result is the same.

Comment: You shouldn't parse the results of find with a while read loop as you are splitting on newlines, which can be contained within filenames.

Comment: @123 So how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started over with a `for` loop and without `find`. All working now!

```
IEXT='.jpg'
for fname in ./*.mp4; do

    [ -e "$fname" ] || continue

    NOEXT=${fname::-4}
        OUPUT=${NOEXT}${IEXT}

        duration=$(ffprobe -i "$fname" -show_format -v quiet | sed -n 's/duration=//p'| sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//')
        space=$(awk '{print $1/$2}' <<<"$duration 5")

ffmpeg -ss "$space" -i "$fname" -vf "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,"$space")',scale='
if(gt(a,4/3),206,-1):if(gt(a,4/3),-1,154)',pad=w=206:h=155:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=black,tile=4x1" -aspect 4:3
 -frames:v 1 -vsync vfr "$OUPUT" -y

done
```